# Best way to code my project

Tags: php, mysql, json

I hope you people can give me some advice.  I am new to programming, especially the back end side of things but it looks like the next project I want to try will require it.

I have been learning Swift 2 and want to create an app that can send basic info and hopefully also the odd image to a database on my website.  I also want to have a function that can check said database for information and return it.

From what I've found out and been playing with, it seems that I should create a MySQL database then use PHP and JSON to connect with Swift 2.  Is this the method you would recommend or is there a better way?

Also, can I just confirm that it is definitely possible to update the database this way?

I don't have any experience but I have been finding Swift 2 easy enough and PHP/JSON don't seem overly difficult.  This is currently just for learning purposes so security is not my biggest priority but it will be important down the line....

Sorry if this has been posted before, trust me I have looked at hundreds of resources but have yet to find/comprehend anything concrete or up to date.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks to me like a loaded question that has received a loaded answer. Fake!

Comment: What do you mean??  I honestly just want to know the easiest way for someone like me (no real experience) to update/retrieve data from a database I want to put on my website using Swift 2 and an iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to set up here is an API server. The workflow for an API server looks something like this:

1. App sends a request to the API server.
2. API server processes the request. Talks to DB. Thinks deep thoughts. Usually prepares something to be sent back to the app.
3. API server returns a response to the app (usually in JSON or HTML).

The front end AJAX stuff (the server calls and response processing) will need to be handled in Swift, but setting up the API server and handling requests can actually be done with any modern web server back end scripting language (eg. PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, Javascript, Go, etc.).

You'll find that there are a lot of people out there who belong to camps with dogs in fights with other camps, but truth be told there is no one perfect solution. Different back scripting languages are great at handling different things, so I'd look at what operations it is exactly that you're trying to perform on the back end and move in that direction.

Personally, I find Ruby and Rails to be a good way to get an API server up and running in a hurry (others will probably debate this; take it as a matter of personal opinion, albeit one you may want to look into). Rails does this nice thing where it handles all of the base infrastructure for your server without requiring much from you (hooray!). There are great resources online for getting started with Ruby and learning Rails (do one, then the other unless you're brilliant or mad). My other personal favorite is using Node.js in conjunction with Express.js to handle any and all back end stuff. Both have their ups and downs.

As far as DB's go, I'd stick with what you know best. If you're a SQL guy then go with a solid SQL platform like PostGreSQL. Again, back to the camps with dogs fighting each other analogy, you'll find this to be hotly debated.

When it comes to security, there are two things I make sure to do. First, make sure you are ALWAYS working on an HTTPS connection. Second, build your server to follow RESTful API conventions.

Comment: Agreed with most of your answer except the last point "make nothing but POST requests from the client" is wrong, try RESTFUL API instead

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Editing now.